# I am not able to run the binary file on my samsung mobile using abd shell

Tags: android, c, compiler-errors, adb, cross-compiling

i m trying to directly run the convolution operation on my samsung mobile, to do that i have written the simple conv program in c and created the executable using,

```
rm-linux-gnueabi-gcc basic_conv_program.c -o conv_program
```

later i pushed the file to path data/local/tmp inside my mobile using adb shell.
then entered adb shell, tried to execute the file

```
./data/local/tmp/conv_program
```

its throwing file not found error, but if i do ls, i can see the file.

I checked the file permission, its -rwxrwxrwx

what can i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you mean to type "./data/local..."?  With that leading ., that would only work from the root directory.  Get rid of it